# Connect Windows 7 to VPN hosted on Mac OS X Server 10.6

Tags: windows-7, vpn, osx-server

We have a Mac OS X Server setup to be a VPN as well, we also have a freelancer who wants log in to the Mac OS X VPN on our server, but he keeps getting errors. I have tested the VPN with our Macs, and they connect fine using Snow Leopard.

Our VPN type is L2TP over IPSec and we use a shared secret instead of a certificate.

Does anyone have any pointers for me?

Comment: I've attempted a similar connection: WinXP client to OSX server via VPN without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into this one myself. If you are using a NAT router (airport extreme, along with most routers under $600) on either end (client or server or both) you might be getting caught up with how windows handles IPSec.

Fairly painless to resolve with a small edit to the registry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926179/